# Undefined reference to .so file in C++

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, openfoam

Working on Open Foam, created my model and sub-model, library is compiled successfully but when I try to compile solver using the same library linker is giving me this error

```
/home/bilal/OpenFOAM/bilal-2.1.0/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/lib/liblagrangianIntermediate_splash_new.so: undefined reference to `Foam::KinematicCloud<Foam::Cloud<Foam::KinematicParcel<Foam::particle> > >::splashDirection(Foam::Vector<double> const&, Foam::Vector<double> const&, Foam::Vector<double> const&) const' 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/bilal/OpenFOAM/bilal-2.1.0/platforms/linux64GccDPOpt/bin/reactingParcelFilmFoam_neu_splash] Error 1
```

Does anyone know what this error is ? I'm using GCC on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: This error comes 'from' a .so file and not 'to'.

Comment: Are you remembering to supply the linker arguments in the correct order? Also remember that you have to explicitly tell the compiler which libraries to link. 

See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc) for more info.

Comment: brbbhatti, can you post your code and I will try to help with an answer.